# Why does this simple java program for primes doesn't count 1

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int c = 0;
        int i,j;
        for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if(i % j == 0) {
                    c = c+1;
                }
            }

            if(c == 2) { 
                System.out.println("the prime number is: "+i);
            }
            c = 0;
         }
    }
}
```

[java program to find primes below an integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFyZP.jpg)

Also, if I change `c==3` then the output that it shows is that the primes are 4 and 9. Why is it so?

Comment: You should set "c=0;" in at the first outer loop.

Comment: Just a note: Of course you're entitled to however you like your code to be formatted, but when asking others to understand your code it often helps formatting it in a way that is consistent with what others expect. As for your question, I'm sure you'll figure out what you're doing if you start sprinkling comments about what each part is *supposed* to do throughout your program.

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani yes maybe, but it does work anyway to give a correct output. However, my question is how does the program know that 1 is not a prime number? and how exactly does changing the value of c alters the output?

Comment: [`1` is not a prime](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/one.html).

Comment: Why not debug your code? That way you'll see step-by-step what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

According to prime number definition: A prime number is a natural number that is greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers.If you  change c=3 then it giving output 4 and 9 because,
initially c=0 1*4=4 -> c=1, 4*1=4 -> c=2, 2*2=4 -> c=3,final count is 3. Like that for 9 1*9=9 -> c=1, 9*1=9 -> c=2, 3*3=9 -> c=3,
here also count is 3